# Generate output file name in accordance to input file names

Tags: python

Below is a script to read velocity values from molecular dynamics trajectory data. I have many trajectory files with the name pattern as below:

```
waters1445-MD001-run0100.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0200.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0300.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0400.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0500.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0600.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0700.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0800.traj
waters1445-MD001-run0900.traj
waters1445-MD001-run1000.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0100.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0200.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0300.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0400.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0500.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0600.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0700.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0800.traj
waters1445-MD002-run0900.traj
waters1445-MD002-run1000.traj
```

Each file has 200 frames of data to analyse. So I planned in such a way where this code is supposed to read in each traj file (shown above) one after another, and extract the velocity values and write in a specific file (text_file = open("Output.traj.dat", "a") corresponding to the respective input trajectory file.

So I defined a function called 'loops(mmm)', where 'mmm' is a trajectory file name parser to the function 'loops'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
always put #!/usr/bin/env python at the shebang
'''
#from __future__ import print_function
from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile as Dataset
import itertools as itx
import sys
#####################


def loops(mmm): 
  inputfile = mmm

  for FRAMES in range(0,200):
      frame = FRAMES
      text_file = open("Output.mmm.dat", "a")

      def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return itx.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

    formatxyz = "%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f"
    formatxyz_size = 6
    formatxyzshort = "%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f"
    formatxyzshort_size = 3

    #ncfile = Dataset(inputfile, 'r')
    ncfile = Dataset(ppp, 'r')

    variableNames = ncfile.variables.keys()
    #print variableNames

    shape = ncfile.variables['coordinates'].shape
    '''
    do the header
    '''

    print 'title ' + str(frame)
    text_file.write('title ' + str(frame) + '\n')
    print "%5i%15.7e" % (shape[1],ncfile.variables['time'][frame])
    text_file.write("%5i%15.7e" % (shape[1],ncfile.variables['time']\
    [frame]) + '\n')

    '''
    do the velocities
    '''
    try:
        xyz = ncfile.variables['velocities'][frame]
        temp = grouper(2, xyz, "")

        for i in temp:
            z = tuple(itx.chain(*i))
            if (len(z) == formatxyz_size): 
                print formatxyz % z
                text_file.write(formatxyz % z + '\n')
            elif (len(z) == formatxyzshort_size): 
                print formatxyzshort % z
                text_file.write(formatxyzshort % z + '\n' )

    except(KeyError):
        xyz = [0] * shape[2] 
        xyz = [xyz] * shape[1]
        temp = grouper(2, xyz, "")

        for i in temp:
            z = tuple(itx.chain(*i))
            if (len(z) == formatxyz_size): 
                print formatxyz % z
            elif (len(z) == formatxyzshort_size): 
                print formatxyzshort % z
            x = ncfile.variables['cell_angles'][frame]
            y = ncfile.variables['cell_lengths'][frame]

 #text_file.close()


# program starts - generation of file name
for md in range(1,3):
   if md < 10:
      for pico in range(100,1100, 100):
        if  pico >= 1000:
            kkk = "waters1445-MD00{0}-run{1}.traj".format(md,pico)
            loops(kkk)
        elif pico < 1000:
            kkk = "waters1445-MD00{0}-run0{1}.traj".format(md,pico)
            loops(kkk)

        #print kkk
```

At the (# program starts - generation of file name) line, the code supposed to generate the file name and accordingly call the function and extract the velocity and dump the values in (text_file = open("Output.mmm.dat", "a")

When execute this code, the program is running, but unfortunately could not produce output files according the input trajectory file names.

I want the output file names to be:

```
velo-waters1445-MD001-run0100.dat
velo-waters1445-MD001-run0200.dat
velo-waters1445-MD001-run0300.dat
velo-waters1445-MD001-run0400.dat
velo-waters1445-MD001-run0500.dat
.
.
.
```

I could not trace where I need to do changes.

Comment: Can you check the indentation in the above code? It looks like opening the file happens inside a `for` loop, but writing happens outside of it.

Comment: yea.. thats how I wrote. First the mmm file will open. That is the trajectory file. Then for that trajectory file it suppose open output file and write. The code is running. Anyway is the algorithm need to alter?

Answer (score 0):

Your code's indentation is broken: The first assignment to `formatxyz` and the following code is not aligned to either the `def grouper`, nor the `for FRAMES`.

The main problem may be (like Johannes commented on already) the time when you open the file(s) for writing and when you actually write data into the file.

Check:

```
for FRAMES in range(0,200):
    frame = FRAMES
    text_file = open("Output.mmm.dat", "a")
```

The output file is named (hardcoded) `Output.mmm.dat`. Change to `"Output.{0}.dat".format(mmm)`. But then, the variable `mmm` never changes inside the loop. This may be ok, if all frames are supposed to be written to the same file.

Generally, please work on the names you choose for variables and functions. `loops` is very generic, and so are `kkk` and `mmm`. Be more specific, it helps debugging. If you don't know what's happening and where your programs go wrong, insert `print("dbg> do (a)")` statements with some descriptive text and/or use [the Python debugger](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html) to step through your program. Especially interactive debugging is essential in learning a new language and new concepts, imho.